# getElementById not working on td elements

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to access table elements with getElementById but this code is giving me "null" as the console log? Does getElementById not work with tables?

```html
<tr>
  <td id="num1"></td>
  <td id="num2"></td>
  <td id="num3"></td>
  <td id="num4"></td>
  <td id="num5"></td>
</tr>
<script>
  console.log(document.getElementById('num3'));
</script>
```

Comment: You need to wrap your `<tr>` in a `<table>`.

Comment: @R3tep why remove the runnable snippet that reproduces the behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. While I can reproduce your problem by copy/pasting your code "as is", it works fine **if** you put the `<tr>` and `<script>` elements in places they are allowed (i.e. as a child of a `<table>` and not as a sibling of `<tr>` respectively).

Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/) to identify errors in your HTML.

```html
<table><tr>
    <td id="num1"></td>
    <td id="num2"></td>
    <td id="num3"></td>
    <td id="num4"></td>
    <td id="num5"></td>
</tr></table>
<script>
    console.log(document.getElementById('num3'));
</script>
```